# Pick a unique activity for each day of the week

Tags: usability, interface, user-centered-design

I am making an app that creates custom marathon training schedules and I want the user to be able to pick one of 7 activities for each day of the week without picking the same one twice. I made a basic table that doesn't allow any repeated days or activities. It functions ok, but I don't think it is very user-friendly. Is there a more intuitive way to go about this?

This is what I have now:
[image: Here is what I have now]

Comment: By the way, if you have the rest option two times, it isn't really unique activity...

Comment: Change ux to non-serif fonts. Serif fonts look unhealthy.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Create a repository with actions from where they can be dragged to days.

[image]

The question is what happens when you try to drag an item to a day that is already occupied.

1. Replace the item and send the previous one to the repository
2. Swap both items. In this case, if you start with a preset for every day you don't even need the repository.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the clarity and the mockup, but it's essentially the same answer as Awesh has given.

Comment: This is what I will do, probably with a preset for each day so someone who is looking to make a schedule quickly can use the defaults. Thanks! Also thanks @awesh

Comment: Something just occurred to me, how mobile-friendly do you think this method is?

Comment: Thanks for the wireframe.. it would be mobile/tablet friendly.

Comment: @BartGijssens I did read Awesh's answer but didn’t realize it was meant exaclty as mine.

Comment: @Awesh A picture says apparently more than a thousand words

Comment: @johnmitsch The idea behind this concept is that it is touch screen friendly, so it should work for mobile too.

Answer (score 8):

Try drag and drop.. have a table or placeholders for Weekdays and user should be able to drag and drop activities (Run, Rest...) for each day.. it would be quite clear to the user that he/she would need to select 1 activity for each day.

Answer (score 4):

Since every choice must be unique, you can highlight this fact in your choice matrix after each selection, reducing the complexity offered to the user:

[image]

Additionally, you can add a 'reset' button, letting the user start over if they want to start afresh.

This is a multi-choice matrix, and unless there is an specific need to be different, the standard layout in your screenshot works very well to explain the requirement and lets the user make their choices easily. While drag-and-drops and dropdowns may seem interesting choices, they increase the number of clicks and the cognitive load in understanding and distributing choices.

Comment: Considering the real estate (assuming it is for mobile devices not for tablets), UI will be change drastically. In that case you can hide the previous task to save the real estate with a cue to show it again.

Comment: The OP didn't mention making an interface for a mobile device, so my assumption is that its a 'web app' being talked about. The UI for a mobile device would certainly be different.

Answer (score 2):

It is extremely complex problem, because your user may want to change picket combination. Imagine that he/she decides to do that in step "Sunday". One click needs to change one of previous answers.

Also consider how people makes plans. For me I do plans accoding to time, not actions, so natural for me would be to assign activity to a day, not a day to activity.

[image]